# Не получается подключить библиотеку OpenGL

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2019

Не могу никак подключить библиотеку OpenGL[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже куда только не сувала эту библиотку в разные папки, у меня эта библиотека уже по всему компьютеру. Но вопрос у меня такой: Почему VS ищет библиотеку с названием freeglut**d**.lib??? Если у меня везде она называется freeglut.lib! Может в этом ошибка? Где в VS посмотреть где он ищет файл и вообще почему он ищет файл с таким названием?

Comment: `d` - от слова "дебажный". В дебажных билдах библиотеки с суффиксом d, в релизных - без. Подробнее не знаю.

Comment: попробуй через vcpkg